# c free temporary pointer to struct

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have a small problem in c, 
i sort some data, with a bubble sort, (change a <=> b with a tmp)
Let's see some code, you'll understand.

```
void ft_sort_dico(t_dico **dico)
{
    int y;
    t_dico *tmp;

    tmp = (t_dico *)malloc(sizeof(t_dico));
    y = 0;
    while (dico[y])
    {
        if (dico[y + 1] && ft_strcmp(dico[y]->key, dico[y + 1]->key) > 0)
        {
            tmp = dico[y];
            dico[y] = dico[y + 1];
            dico[y + 1] = tmp;
            y = -1;
        }
        y++;
    }
    free(tmp); <- error
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what the error is, so I'm going to assume it's some sort of memory corruption and tell you to apply [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: Remove statements tmp = (t_dico *)malloc(sizeof(t_dico)); and free(tmp);  The code will work. As you donot need malloc/free at all. You are just trying to use tmp to swap pointers.

Comment: To know what you have allocated (or attempted to allocate), you need to show the definition of `t_dico` what is presumably a struct or typedef...

Comment: the assignment statements only copy the pointer, not the whole t_diso struct.   (which works correctly for your algorithm).  so no need to ever allocate memory for the `tmp` pointer

Comment: Please do some reading as to what `malloc()` and `free()` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given this posted code:

```
tmp = (t_dico *)malloc(sizeof(t_dico));
y = 0;
while (dico[y])
{
    if (dico[y + 1] && ft_strcmp(dico[y]->key, dico[y + 1]->key) > 0)
    {
        tmp = dico[y];
        dico[y] = dico[y + 1];
        dico[y + 1] = tmp;
        y = -1;
    }
    y++;
}
free(tmp);
```

the `tmp` initially gets a pointer to some allocated memory, via the call to `malloc()`

Then this line overlays that pointer:

```
tmp = dico[y];
```

the result is a memory leak

Then the code passes a pointer to one of the elements in the `dico` array
(the one from `dico[y]`) to the `free()` function.

to correct this, remove the statement that calls `malloc()` and remove the statement that calls `free()`.

BTW:  this sort algorithm does not actually perform the desired sort.
Suggest implementing a `bubble` or `insertion`  or `selection` sort.

here is the algorithm for a `selection` sort.

Where 'n' is number of entries in array[]

```
for ( c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++ )
{
    position = c;

    for ( d = c + 1 ; d < n ; d++ )
    {
       if ( array[position] > array[d] )
         position = d;
    }
    if ( position != c )
    {
       temp = array[c];
       array[c] = array[position];
       array[position] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You free another pointer than you malloc -- at the point your reach `free`, `tmp` points to `dico[something]`, which is definitely not the memory you allocated at the beginning.

Comment: Yeah Marcus i understood what you mean ... i freed the pointed value, not the new one..
So i add a new variable, after malloc who knows the adress of the original one.

Comment: @RedWine, there is no/zero need for the malloc/free as only pointers are being manipulated during the sort operation, not the whole contents of the structs

Answer (score 1):

`tmp = dico[y];` Here you change the address to which tmp points at. You create a memory leak and the program will crash & burn when you call free.

Comment: Further down, he also does `dico[y+1] = tmp` followed by `free(tmp)` which means that `dico` contains dangling pointers all over the place.

Answer (score -1):

Since you do not want to store the `tmp` pointer, you can just define `tmp` as a local variable and it would be stored at stack and do not require your manual free.

When you call `malloc()`, you specify the block size that would be allocated, while it actually use a slightly more space recording the block size information(and maybe something else). This is why when you call `free()`, the function know how much to free.

In your case, when you call `free(tmp)`, as long as the statement `dico[y + 1] && ft_strcmp(dico[y]->key, dico[y + 1]->key) > 0` become `TRUE` for once, the pointer is no longer pointed to the memory you allocate before (would be some `dico[y]`). The `free()` function do not know how mch to free thus return an error.

Comment: `tmp` needs to be a pointer, as only the pointers are being manipulated, not the whole contents of the structs.  So, while this 'fix' would eliminate the current problem, it would raise a new one.